# Rendering Nested Comments In React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement nested comments in React. Basically I got the code currently like this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/81191/).

The code looks like the following:

```
var nested = [...]

function Comment({ comment }) {
  const nestedComments = comment.map(comment => {
    return <Comment comment={comment} />;
  });

  console.log(nestedComments)

  return (
    <div key={comment.id}>
      <span>{comment.body}</span>
      {nestedComments}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Comment comment={nested}/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

I'm getting an error like the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: comment.map is not a function
at Comment (eval at transform.run (VM70 browser.js:5811), <anonymous>:947:31)
at VM134 react-dom.js:4767
at measureLifeCyclePerf (VM134 react-dom.js:4537)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (VM134 react-dom.js:4766)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (VM134 react-dom.js:4741)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (VM134 react-dom.js:4649)
at Object.mountComponent (VM134 react-dom.js:11551)
at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (VM134 react-dom.js:10442)
at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (VM134 react-dom.js:6176)
at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (VM134 react-dom.js:5995)
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: This check out this answer:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193722/nested-comments-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your structure is like

```
var nested= [
    {comment_id: '..', 
     comment_body: '..',
     comments: [{...}]
    },
    ...
]
```

In this case you should change you function to pass the comments array the second time and check whether the nested comments are present or not

Try

```
var nested = [...]

function Comment({ comment }) {

  const nestedComments = null;
  if(typeof comment === 'array') 
    nestedComments= comment.map(comment => {
    return <Comment comment={comment.comments} />;
  });

  console.log(nestedComments)

  return (
    <div key={comment.id}>
      <span>{comment.body}</span>
      {nestedComments}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Comment comment={nested}/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Using your code in his his jsfiddle seems not working.. https://jsfiddle.net/9afdkb4b/